# jQuery dialog box delayed CSS change in Firefox, but I'm not seeing corresponding changes in dev console

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox

We have added a jQuery dialog box for logging in to our site:
http://www.knowledgecity.com/index.html

It seems to work fine in Chrome and Safari, but when we browse the page on Firefox and click on the "Log In" button in the header and wait ~12 seconds then all of the sudden the dialog box's CSS seems to get messed up.

What makes this issue difficult to diagnose is that the CSS in the dev console for the elements that are changing do not have any CSS rules that are changing in the dev console.

[Broken CSS for Dialog Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1wV7.png)

I am really having trouble tracking down what is causing the problem. The dialog box CSS breaks for Firefox in both Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. Again, the CSS tends to break somewhere around 10-15 seconds after the page loads which is a bizarre delay and I'm not sure what is triggering it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has probably something to do with `resload.js`. Before css messing up, console logs lots of "The operation is insecure" errors. Just as css messes up, these errors stop.

Comment: Thank you, it looked like it had something to do with the way the Firefox allows Javascript to read CSS rules from within an external resource (jQuery UI CSS files hosted on Google's CDN).